# php remove forward slash from php URL

Tags: php, magento

I've tried everything I can find to remove the slashes that are being added to this:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'c2c_used_by_game');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
echo ('<form method="post">');
echo ('<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">');
foreach ($options as $option)

    {
        echo '<option value="'.Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result',array ('?c2c_used_by_game='=>$option['value'])).'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
    }   
echo ('</select>');
echo ('</form>');
}
```

So that's outputing a select dropdown that creates a link such as on [here](http://magentowebsite.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?c2c_used_by_game=/561/).

I need one stinking slash removed after the equal sign so its `c2c_used_by_game=561` and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: It's a dirty hack, but you could explode the result by `c2c_used_by_game` and then strip slashes from `$split[1] = str_replace('/','',$split[1]);` and then recompile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_query` in the second parameter to construct query properly:

```
Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result', array('_query' => array ('c2c_used_by_game' => $option['value'])));
```

More info on `getUrl` function usage can be found on the Magento [Wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters).

Comment: Thank you so much!  And thanks for the wiki.  I was looking for a PHP based solution, didn't even think to go Magento.

Answer (score 1):

```
array ('?c2c_used_by_game='=>(str_replace('/','',$option['value'])))).

'">'.str_replace('/','',$option['label']).'</option>';
```

Comment: Mihai, that didn't do the trick.  I'm not sure I fully understand what you're saying WASaquatch.  I'm an amature with PHP.

Comment: @BridgeRoad Can you give more details,do a var_dump on that array

Comment: array(1) { ["?c2c_used_by_game="]=> string(3) "936" }